# WCF - run code after AppStart - but not in AppStart

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container

i'm trying to set up some code that needs access the PerRequest lifestyle. this lifestyle can't be access from within the AppStart of the global.asax.

How can i effectively run initialization code on a wcf service outside of appstart?

this is so that i can configure what documents are versioned in my RavenDb - to do this i have to specify the perrequest ifestyle - doing this in app start throws an exception.

Comment: So if Application_start is not sufficient where do you expect the code to run and how is it related to per request execution?

Answer (score 0):

Code that use the PerRequest lifestyle runs by definition per request.

You could split your initialisation code in two parts

- What is not dependant on the per request lifecycle runs in Application_start
- What is dependant on per request lifecycle runs as the first code in each request

Typically the binding of your ioc containers should be in application_start